# PNG File Can't Open

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game using python and pygame but for some reason or another pycharm isn't able to open my png file of a race car and I get this error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Zack's PC/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/main1.py", line 14, in <module>
    carImg = pygame.image.load(':/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')
pygame.error: Couldn't open :/Users/Zack's PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png
```

Here is the code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width= 900
display_height=600
black= (0,0,0)
white= (255,255,255)
red= (255,0,0)


screen= pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Race Car')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
carImg = pygame.image.load(':/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))


x = (display_height * 0.45)
y = (display_width * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True


    car(x,y)
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You're missing the drive, no? `...load('C:/Users/...')`?

Comment: Here's a hint: what is the first character in the path you are trying to use with `pygame.image.load`? What is the first character in the path that Python says your source file has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the drive letter, change:

```
Img = pygame.image.load(':/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')
```

to:

```
Img = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')
```